# Chrome bug with pointer-events and mouse-scroll?

Tags: css, google-chrome

Fiddle to reproduce:
Resize this until vertical scrollbar appears: http://jsfiddle.net/yxf1v60x/2/embedded/result/

Expected behavior: mousewheel scrolls when used over the yellow area.

Observed behavior: doesn't work in Chrome, works fine in Firefox.

---

HTML code:

```
<div class="parent"><input /><div class="child"><div class="subChild"><input /></div></div></div>
```

CSS code:

```
html,body{

  overflow:hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.parent {
  pointer-events:none;        
  position: absolute;
  z-index:10;
  top:0px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0px;
  background-color:#ff0000;
  height: auto;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
.child {
    pointer-events:auto;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:11;
    top:50px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom: 0;
    max-height: 100%;
    background-color:#0000FF;
}
.subChild{
    height: 500px;
    background-color:yellow;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

---

So I'm not sure what's going on here: pointer-events clearly work on the yellow area, since the related input element is clickable. Scrolling via keyboard also works (try with page up/page down with focus on yellow area).

a) Is this a Chrome bug?

b) Can I avoid it while keeping both parent and child absolute positioned? I do not wish to have pointer-events on the parent element.

Comment: Confirmed this on a different use case, and filed a bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=818444

Comment: @Labu This seems fixed on version  84.0.4147.89 of Chrome. Sometime between March 2020 and now. You should let them know that they fixed it (without knowing it :-) )

Comment: Meant to come back after updating the Chrome ticket, which has now been closed. Thanks for the heads up @pkExec :)

Comment: Hey @Labu, I'm here for our two-year check up. Let's see....yes I see the bug is regressed again. That'll be 50$. See you on our next two-year check up?

Comment: Bug Monopoly? _Go straight to jail!_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is going on: The `overflow-y` attribute, and with it the scrolling-capability, is on the `pointer-events: none` parent.

Firefox seems to handle pointer-events in this way:

> If one of the element's children has pointer-events explicitly set to allow that child to be the target of mouse events, then any events targeting that child will pass through the parent as the event
>   travels along the parent chain, **and trigger event listeners on the
>   parent** as appropriate.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

While Chrome *does not trigger* the event on a parent with `pointer-events: none`. This might actually be a bug and you could/should try to report it. Good catch!

Moving the `overflow-y` attribute to a container could be the solution, as long as scrolling on the parent is okay, since the parent's `pointer-events: none` would prevent all actions on itself, while passing the mouse event to the scrollable container.

```css
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.parent {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: #f00;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 11;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
  pointer-events: auto;
  background-color: #00f;
}

.subChild {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">
    <input />
    <div class="child">
      <div class="subChild">
        <input />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```